# Query optimization with many joins and date filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a query that runs, but is horribly slow. There's multiple tables involved that all have the same named column for date and id. Because the number of rows is huge (3M+), filtering by date is necessary to speed it up. I had done a rudimentary join job, but I'm wondering how to optimize further.

The query that runs terribly slow looks like:

```
select 

A.date
,A.id
,A.col3
,B.id2
,B.colR
,B.colS
,C.colX
,C.colY
,C.colZ

from table1 A
    left join table2 B on A.id = B.id
    left join table3 on B.id2 = C.id2

where A.date = '2017-06-01' and A.col3 = 'test' and B.id2 is not NULL
```

Now table 2 has a `date` field as well, which I'd like to filter on as well. I rewrote the query like so and this runs just fine:

```
select 

    A.date
    ,A.id
    ,A.col3
    ,B.id2
    ,B.colR
    ,B.colS

from

(select date, id, col3 from table1 where date='2017-06-01' and col3='test') A
left join (select date, id, colR, colS from table2 where date='2017-06-01') B on A.id=B.id where B.colR is not NULL
```

But now comes the question of how I join on table 3. My approach of slapping on another `left join` to the join I already have doesn't seem to work in the same way that I was approaching it in my initial, poorly optimized query. That approach looks like:

```
select 

    A.date
    ,A.id
    ,A.col3
    ,B.id2
    ,B.colR
    ,B.colS
    ,C.colX
    ,C.colY
    ,C.colZ

from

(select date, id, col3 from table1 where date='2017-06-01' and col3='test') A
left join (select date, id, id2, colR, colS from table2 where date='2017-06-01') B on A.id=B.id where B.colR is not NULL
left join (select id2, colX, colY, colZ from table3) C on B.id2 = C.id2
```

How should I go about joining on table 3 if the query immediately above doesn't work? The specific error I'm getting is:

`Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 33, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'left'.`

Which is at the second `left join` I have in the statement above.

Comment: And I'm at a loss on what your question is.  I get that you have a query that runs slow.  Your question has several queries.

Comment: Question clarified. I can get a left join to work just fine, but I want to join again with another table and I keep getting an error suggesting that's not the way to do it.

Comment: If you get error, you should definitely include that

Comment: Don't really understand why instead of joining the tables, you're creating a derived table into the from -part. Maybe it should be simpler just to join the table without any additional select clauses?

Comment: Why do you not just join the tables? Your join syntax is as close to abuse as it can be including a subselect instead of just joining the tables. Nedlessly overcomplicated - look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: @JamesZ, if I just join the tables on directly, the query takes upwards of 30 minutes because of how many rows are involved. Tables 1 and 2 both have the same `date` field. In my original query, I'm basically selecting all dates from table 2, then filtering the resultant join by the date which takes forever. I can speed it up by doing a join-select where I specify the date, but I don't know how to join multiple tables on after that.

Comment: Why you no check colR is not null in table2 first? So, it will like this: left join (select date, id, id2, colR, colS from table2 where date='2017-06-01' and colR is not null) B on A.id=B.id. Or let where in the end query.

Comment: When you said you want to filter on a date in table2, too, I supposed you'd add somthing like `left join table2 B on A.id = B.id and B.date='2017-06-01'`. But you didn't. Why? This additional criterion would only get you table2 record with that date. And if you really want to filter your result rows by that date, you'll make this an inner join. Would this give you the desired results or is it another result you are after?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution. In my original query, if I just added a `and B.FactDate = '2017-06-01'` clause at the end of the `where` statement, that gets me the optimized query I'm after.

Comment: No. Putting this in the `WHERE` clause turns your join into an inner join. If you do want an inner join, then you should call this `INNER JOIN`. If you want to stay with an outer join, on the other hand, add the criterion to the `ON` clause instead.